# Set lock screen wallpaper of Android device programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, set, wallpaper

There is bunch of wallpaper applications where you can change lock screen wallpaper separate from main wallpaper. If I am not mistaken from `API 24` it is possible to do such kind of thing, but I find very few articles related to this besides they are TOO old.

Comment: Have you tried [`WallpaperManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`WallpaperManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) has a number of methods to help you get or set the specific wallpapers. As you want the lock screen wallpaper, use [`FLAG_LOCK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#FLAG_LOCK). Relevant methods include:

[`getWallpaperFile(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperFile(int))

[`setBitmap(Bitmap fullImage, Rect visibleCropHint, boolean allowBackup, int which)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean,%20int))

Answer (score 2):

```
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)
```

Comment: how to use it in service